# Use filtered list in datatables to send multiple emails

Tags: datatables

I'd like to be able to send emails based on a search completed in Datatables.  I use a json array created from a mysql db and serverside datatables.js processing to create the table. The table creates a filtered list (Showing 1 to 35 of 35 entries (filtered from 60 total entries)), and I'd like to be able to send an email to those 35 people.  I'm very new to ajax and javascript, but have some experience in php.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

It's absolutely possible.
You may need to extract your visible rows data:

```
var selectedRows = datatable.rows({filter:'applied'}).data()
```

Pass that data via [`$.ajax()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) call to your backend php-script and perform necessary 'e-mail' job server side.

Without your code and knowing exact environment, I believe, that's the best I could say.

Comment: tried:

$('#export').click(function () {
$.ajax({
    url     : 'emget.php',
    type    : 'post',
    data    : table.column(4,{search:'applied'}).data().toArray(),
    dataType: 'json',
    success : function(returnedData) {
        console.log(returnedData);
    }
});
});

When I view the output, it seems to put out the correct number of records, but it says "Undefined" for each record it seems to try to export. Column 4 has the email addresses that I would need to pass to PHP.

Comment: As long as you use POST method, what's `var_dump($_POST)` output?

Answer (score 0):

I tried:

```
$('#export').click(function () {
$.ajax({
    url     : 'emget.php',
    type    : 'post',
    data    : table.column(4,{search:'applied'}).data().toArray(),
    dataType: 'json',
    success : function(returnedData) {
        console.log(returnedData);
    }
});
```

});

When I view the output, it seems to put out the correct number of records, but it says "Undefined" for each record it seems to try to export.  Column 4 has the email addresses that I would need to pass to PHP.